# Is there a simple way to combine a text and icon in an NSCell in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to create a very simple selection list widget based on NSOutlineView. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display an icon and a label right next to it, which is really the expected behavior in all the mainstream implementations of that kind of widget out there (iTunes, mail, Finder,...).

So far I am just binding two separate cells, but then when I'm expanding the tree, the icon cell grows larger and a gap appears between the icon and its accompanying label. I know I can probably overcome this problem by extending NSCell and provide a custom class, but as what I'm trying to achieve is really the standard thing, I can't be resigned to accept that there isn't a simpler solution.

Candide

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, there isn't a 'text and icon' cell that you can just use, fresh out of the box as you would like. However, when I was working on a project, I found that Apple released some sample code that implements this, since it is such a common idiom.

This can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SourceView/index.html), specifically ImageAndTextCell.h/m

It can help teach you about UI customization by reading through this example, but scratching that, just dropping the ImageAndTextCell straight into your project should do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ImageAndTextcell to combine text and icon..
you can create ImageAndTextcell like this [Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008831)